# Disabling hyperthreading

Tags: bios

From my understanding disabling hyperthreading can only be done at the BIOS-level, and some BIOSes don't have the option to disable hyperthreading. Is there any repository of patched BIOSes with the `disable hyperthreading` option present? (in my case and looking for a patched BIOS for an *MSI Computer Corp. Notebook Computer GE70 0ND-033US*)

Comment: I am curious, is there any advantage of having hyperthreading disabled?

Comment: @ComFreek When running a mono-core process, which happens to me quite a lot when developing some programs that I don't have the time to multithread... it's really really annoying :/ Also many other applications don't make use of multi-core, such as my voice recognition software or even a single Chrome tab (maybe the latter does a bit but very often I see one tab maxing at 100% of one core). I am a victim of the multi-core marketing...

Comment: @ComFreek One problem I had with HT is that a thread scheduled on one virtual core degrades the performance of the of the partner virtual core. This introduces disturbances in single threaded benchmarks.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I don't get how disabling HT would improve your situation. Single threaded applications don't benefit from HT, but don't suffer either. If two independent applications run on different virtual cores, you might even benefit from HT a bit. The only problem with HT I see is that the task scheduler isn't ideal and sometimes schedules two threads on partnering virtual cores instead of independent physical cores.